# State name spellcheck code not working with two word state names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, spelling

I am working on vetting someone else's state spellchecker. The test data they ran seemed to work fine, but trying a different data set, it doesn't seem to be able to get past the first word "North" in a state name.

I need the code to be able to work with state names with two words.

This is the code:

```
import sys
!pip install pyspellchecker
from spellchecker import SpellChecker
#from google.colab import files
import pandas as pd
import io

#Implement spellcheck.
spell=SpellChecker()
for ind in newDF.index:
  stateWordList = newDF['State'][ind].split()
  if len(stateWordList) == 1:
    #print(True)
    if stateWordList[0] in spell:
      pass
    else:
      correctState = input("'{}' is not a valid state, please enter a correct spelling:".format(stateWordList[0]))
      newDF.at[ind, 'State'] = correctState
  else:
    misspelledState = False in (stateWord in spell for stateWord in stateWordList)
    if misspelledState == True:
      pass
    else:
      correctState = input("'{}' is not a valid state, please enter a correct spelling:".format(stateWordList[0]))
      newDF.at[ind, 'State'] = correctState
```

Instead, it isn't seeing North WhateverState as valid, and returns:

```
'North' is not a valid state, please enter a correct spelling:
```

Does it need a condition specifically for two word names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `else` statement, you have a logic error

```py
  else:
    misspelledState = False in (stateWord in spell for stateWord in stateWordList)
    if misspelledState == True:
      pass
    else:
      correctState = input("'{}' is not a valid state, please enter a correct spelling:".format(stateWordList[0]))
      newDF.at[ind, 'State'] = correctState
```

Let's see `misspelledState = False in (stateWord in spell for stateWord in stateWordList)`, if all the words in `stateWordList` is well spelled, you are checking with `misspelledState = False in (True, True, ...)`, the result will be `False`.

Then go to the `if-else` condition, it will go to `else` condition where outputs the correction message:

```py
    if misspelledState == True:
      pass
    else:
      correctState = input("'{}' is not a valid state, please enter a correct spelling:".format(stateWordList[0]))
      newDF.at[ind, 'State'] = correctState
```

You can use

```py
misspelledState = all([stateWord in spell for stateWord in stateWordList])
```

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thank you for the clear explanation, I understand it better now.